# How to create a draggable and resizable div using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drag-and-drop, resizable

I want to create a transparent box which can be used to mask the webpage content and help me only view a particular area.

I tried doing this using JQuery Object.draggable() and Object.resizable() but it was not maintaining the size of box.

So later I tried a different approach of using 4 different div to and position them accordingly and added Object.draggable() but could not resize the left and right div's width and height.

[image: A child box in a parent container. Parent is draggable but of fixed size. Child is resizable and movable inside parent. Parent can be moved anywhere on the webpage]

Here is the codesandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-frost-wrjq4?file=/index.html

Here is the demo of what I am expecting it to be.

1. Open this link - https://nj.testnav.com/client/index.html#login?username=LGN537831517&password=LLT5P7KN
2. Start the test.
3. Click the user icon and select Line Reader.
   This Line Reader Mask I am trying to reproduce for me.
   [image: Click User Icon from the top and select Line Reader]

Comment: please add the code you used

Comment: @Asmoun Added the codesandbox link in the question.

Comment: @Asmoun I did it. Its working good but I feel code can be trimmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
    #topdiv{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        cursor: move;
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        -ms-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        z-index: 1001;
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        background: #666;
        width: 600px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    #leftdiv{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        cursor: move;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #666;
        z-index: 1001;
        border: 0px solid #fff;
        width: 20px;
        height: 150px;
        top: 50px;
    }
    #rightdiv{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        cursor: move;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #666;
        z-index: 1001;
        border: 0px solid #fff;
        width: 20px;
        height: 150px;
        top: 50px;
        margin-left: 580px;
    }
    #bottomdiv{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        cursor: move;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #666;
        -webkit-border-radius:  0 0 5px 5px;
        -moz-border-radius:  0 0 5px 5px;
        -ms-border-radius:  0 0 5px 5px;
        border-radius:  0 0 5px 5px;
        z-index: 1001;
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        width: 600px;
        height: 60px;
        top: 200px;
    }

#movecursor{
    height: 25px;
    width: 560px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: move;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #9f9f9f;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top-width: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: flex-end;
    -moz-box-align: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-align: flex-end;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -moz-box-align: end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    -webkit-box-pack: space-between;
    -moz-box-pack: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: space-between;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 1002;
    top: 200px;
    margin-left: 20px;
   
}
.glyphicon-move{
    margin: auto;
}
.glyphicon-resize-small{
    background: #eee;
    height: 24px;
    top: 0;
    width: 24px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    cursor: se-resize;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: auto;
}


#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  text-align: center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    

   
    <div id="mydiv">
        
           <div id="topdiv"></div>
            <div id="leftdiv"></div>
            <div id="movecursor"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></i><i id="inResize" class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-small"></i></div>
            <div id="rightdiv"></div>
            <div id="bottomdiv"><i id="outResize" class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-small"></i></div>
         </div>
     
</body>
<script>

dragElement(document.getElementById("topdiv"),document.getElementById("mydiv"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("bottomdiv"),document.getElementById("mydiv"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("leftdiv"),document.getElementById("mydiv"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("rightdiv"),document.getElementById("mydiv"));

dragInner(document.getElementById("movecursor"));
resizeInner(document.getElementById("inResize"));
resizeOuter(document.getElementById("outResize"));
var minUnit=10;
function resizeInner(elmnt){  
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX; console.log(pos3);
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElementExtra;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
        document.getElementById("movecursor").onmousedown=null;
        
    }
    function closeDragElementExtra(){
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
        dragInner(document.getElementById("movecursor"));
    }

  function elementDrag(e) { 
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
   
    //get height and div of respective divs
    
    var top = document.getElementById("topdiv");
    var bottom = document.getElementById("bottomdiv");
    var left = document.getElementById("leftdiv");
    var right = document.getElementById("rightdiv");
    var cursor = document.getElementById("movecursor");
    var outResize=document.getElementById("outResize");
   
    if(pos2>0){ // Y axis
       if(left.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2>=minUnit*2){//console.log('last2');
            right.style.height=(right.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2) + "px";
            left.style.height=(left.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2)+'px';
            cursor.style.top=(cursor.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
            bottom.style.top=(bottom.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
            bottom.style.height=(bottom.getBoundingClientRect().height+pos2) + "px";
            
        }
        else if(top.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2>=minUnit+2){ //console.log('last3');
            top.style.height=(top.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2) + "px";
            left.style.top=(left.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
            right.style.top=(right.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
            cursor.style.top=(cursor.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
            bottom.style.top=(bottom.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
            bottom.style.height=(bottom.getBoundingClientRect().height+pos2) + "px";
        }
    }
    else if(pos2<0 ){
        if(cursor.getBoundingClientRect().height*2+minUnit<= bottom.getBoundingClientRect().height ){
            bottom.style.height=(bottom.getBoundingClientRect().height+pos2) + "px";
            left.style.height=(left.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2) + "px";
            right.style.height=(right.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2) + "px";
            bottom.style.top=(bottom.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
            cursor.style.top=(cursor.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
        }
    }
//if(pos1<=10 && pos1>=-10){ 
    if(pos1>0){ // X axis
        if(cursor.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1>150){ //console.log('>150');
            right.style.marginLeft =(right.offsetLeft-pos1)+'px';
            cursor.style.width =(cursor.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1)+'px';
            right.style.width=(right.getBoundingClientRect().width+pos1) + "px";
        }
        else if(left.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1>minUnit+2 ){
            left.style.width=(left.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
            right.style.marginLeft =(right.offsetLeft-pos1)+'px';
            right.style.width=(right.getBoundingClientRect().width+pos1) + "px";
            cursor.style.marginLeft =(cursor.offsetLeft-pos1)+'px';
        }
    }
    else if(pos1<0 ){  
        if(right.getBoundingClientRect().width+pos1>=minUnit+2){
            right.style.width=(right.getBoundingClientRect().width+pos1) + "px";
            right.style.marginLeft =(right.offsetLeft-pos1)+'px';
            cursor.style.width =(cursor.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1)+'px';
        }
        /*else{ // uncomment this to expand outer div syncronisly
            right.style.marginLeft =(right.offsetLeft-pos1)+'px';
            top.style.width=(top.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
            bottom.style.width=(bottom.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
        }*/
        
      
    }

    }
}

function resizeOuter(elmnt){  
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX; 
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElementExtra;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
        document.getElementById("bottomdiv").onmousedown=null;
        
    }
    function closeDragElementExtra(){
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
        dragElement(document.getElementById("bottomdiv"),document.getElementById("mydiv"));
    }

  function elementDrag(e) { 
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    //console.log(e.clientY+" "+pos4+" "+pos2);
    //get height and div of respective divs
    
    var top = document.getElementById("topdiv");
    var bottom = document.getElementById("bottomdiv");
    var left = document.getElementById("leftdiv");
    var right = document.getElementById("rightdiv");
    var cursor = document.getElementById("movecursor");
    var outResize=document.getElementById("outResize");
    
    if(pos2>0){ // Y axis
       if(cursor.getBoundingClientRect().height*2+minUnit<= bottom.getBoundingClientRect().height){//console.log(23);
            bottom.style.height=(bottom.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2) + "px";
        }
        else if(left.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2>=minUnit+2){//console.log('last');
            if(top.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2>=minUnit+2 ){
                top.style.height=(top.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2) + "px";
                left.style.top=(left.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
                right.style.top=(right.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
            }
            else{
                left.style.height=(left.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2) + "px";
                right.style.height=(right.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2) + "px";
            }
            bottom.style.top=(bottom.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
            cursor.style.top=(cursor.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
        }
    }
    else if(pos2<0 && bottom.getBoundingClientRect().top+bottom.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2<window.innerHeight){
        bottom.style.height=(bottom.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2) + "px";
    }
    if(pos1>0){ // X axis
        if(right.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1>minUnit+1  ){ console.log(1);
            bottom.style.width=(bottom.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
            top.style.width=(top.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
            right.style.width=(right.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
        }
        else if(cursor.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1>150){console.log(2);
            bottom.style.width=(bottom.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
            top.style.width=(top.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
            right.style.marginLeft =(right.offsetLeft-pos1)+'px';
            cursor.style.width =(cursor.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1)+'px';
        }
        else if(left.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1>minUnit+1){console.log(3);
            left.style.width=(left.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
            right.style.marginLeft =(right.offsetLeft-pos1)+'px';
            right.style.width=(right.getBoundingClientRect().width+pos1) + "px";
            cursor.style.marginLeft =(cursor.offsetLeft-pos1)+'px';
        }
    }
    else if(pos1<0 && bottom.getBoundingClientRect().left+bottom.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1<window.outerWidth){
        bottom.style.width=(bottom.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
        top.style.width=(top.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
        right.style.width=(right.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
    }

    }
}


function dragInner(elmnt){
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    
    var top = document.getElementById("topdiv");
    var bottom = document.getElementById("bottomdiv");
    var left = document.getElementById("leftdiv");
    var right = document.getElementById("rightdiv");
    var cursor = document.getElementById("movecursor");
    var outResize=document.getElementById("outResize");
    var tmp=bottom.getBoundingClientRect().height-cursor.getBoundingClientRect().height; //console.log(tmp);//&& tmp>=outResize.offsetHeight
    if(pos2){
        
        if(pos2>0){ //up Y
            if(top.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2>minUnit ){
                top.style.height=top.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2 + "px";
                cursor.style.top=(cursor.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
                left.style.top=(left.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
                right.style.top=(right.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
                bottom.style.height=(bottom.getBoundingClientRect().height+pos2) + "px";
                bottom.style.top=(bottom.offsetTop-pos2) + "px";
            }
        }
        else if(pos2<0){ //down Y
            if(cursor.getBoundingClientRect().height*2+minUnit/2<= bottom.getBoundingClientRect().height){
                top.style.height=top.getBoundingClientRect().height-pos2 + "px";
                cursor.style.top=(cursor.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
                left.style.top=(left.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
                right.style.top=(right.offsetTop-pos2)+'px';
                bottom.style.height=(bottom.getBoundingClientRect().height+pos2) + "px";
                bottom.style.top=(bottom.offsetTop-pos2) + "px";
            }

        }
        
    }
    // console.log(e.clientX+" "+pos3+" "+pos1);
    //console.log('x='+left.offsetWidth+ " "+right.offsetWidth+" ");
    if(pos1 && left.offsetWidth>minUnit && right.offsetWidth>minUnit){  console.log(23);
        if(left.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1>=minUnit+1 && right.getBoundingClientRect().width+pos1*2>=minUnit+1){
            left.style.width=(left.getBoundingClientRect().width-pos1) + "px";
            
            right.style.width=(right.getBoundingClientRect().width+pos1) + "px";
            right.style.marginLeft =(right.offsetLeft-pos1)+'px';
            
            cursor.style.marginLeft =(cursor.offsetLeft-pos1)+'px';
            
        }
    }

            
  }


}

function dragElement(elmnt,elmntParent) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
   //get height and div of parent div
   var divWidth = document.getElementById("topdiv").offsetWidth;
    var divHeight = document.getElementById("topdiv").offsetHeight+document.getElementById("leftdiv").offsetHeight+document.getElementById("bottomdiv").offsetHeight;

    // set the element's new position:
    if((elmntParent.offsetTop - pos2+divHeight)<window.innerHeight && (elmntParent.offsetTop - pos2)>0)
        elmntParent.style.top = (elmntParent.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    if((elmntParent.offsetLeft - pos1+divWidth)<window.outerWidth && elmntParent.offsetLeft - pos1>0)
        elmntParent.style.left = (elmntParent.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    
    
  }

  
}
function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
    

</script>
</html>
```

Here is the CodeSandbox - https://4g0el.codesandbox.io/